# If users writes ' (Apostrophe) it ruins the code, how to stop it?

Tags: php, mysqli, preg-match

so, I have this piece of code:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
       $nameErr = "This field is required";
    } else {
       $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
       if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
           $nameErr = "Only letters allowed";
       }
```

And it works fine, but there is one problem, what if the users writes ' (Apostrophe)?
I tried it myself, and it ruins the code somehow, as it never reaches the database, and I can't add the Apostrophe to the preg_match because that ruins the code itself and doesn't run correctly!

So my question is, how can I stop the user from writting ' (Apostrophe)?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: What kind of crash do you experience? Text of error message would be helpful

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: @nl-x It's just bad indentation.

Comment: Crash? I don't really experience a crash... I have a form in a php file, and when I submit that form it sends it to mysql database, and it works, but when in one of the fields in the form I use a ' (Apostrophe) nothing happens, the form gets submitted but it never reaches or shows in the mysql, which leads me to think the apostrophe ruined the code ...

Comment: @user3037148 so in no way did you think of showing us the mysql code? Try parameterizing your query!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should you stop the user writing apostrophe, or should you **prepare your code for this kind of situation**? Today's an apostrophe, tomorrow's a double quote, and you can't manage every single symbol (think of other alphabets).

If you are directly adding that to a database, escape the symbols using either [`Mysqli`](https://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)'s or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php)'s (or any database management system you use) escape methods. Otherwise, your code might be in real danger, especially because of SQLInjection. A fairly good example of what could happen is shown here, in this comic from [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/327/), but just imagine this input:

`test'); drop table important_data;--`

Yes, you are (at least in this case and after validating it with your regex) covering from that issue, but that could happen in every single place around your code (suppose a comment form, where you could write anything). **ALWAYS escape every single user input**. It will defend you from lots of future issues.

Comment: `addslashes` serves virtually no purpose, please don't make it the first thing you recommend. Always use escaping functions which are specific to the medium you're escaping for.

Comment: Well, he didn't mention about posting it into a database after writing it into a comment. I'll edit that. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: It is never the Users problem, always yours as the coder

Comment: Yeah, better. I'd recommend prepared statements over escaping, but your basic premise is right. :)

Comment: @zzapper exactly, Basically my initial sentence was about that. You can't control the user's input, therefore you should prepare for the worst